# Intro to C: Addition and Looping

Tags: c, debugging, floating-point, calculator, addition

I'm continuing on my quest to mastery C and I'm currently working on an exercise to have my rudimentary calculator continuously to prompt me for two operands and a operator. If the operator is not a '+', it displays an error message. Right now, I'm running into a few problems.

1. When I enter '+' it shows up two times. There is NOTHING I can find in my code that indicate that this would happen.
2. The first operand exhibits the same problem. I also do not know how to tell my code that I am done inputting.
3. Second operand is fine, but I still do not know how to terminate input.
4. Right after it shows the results, it loops back correctly but gives me an error message before prompting again.

http://tinypic.com/r/34ew5cx/6

NOTE: I know that you use lf to read double numbers in scanf, but for some reason lf isn't working for me and f is working just fine so disregard :)

Any observations are appreciated, along with any general suggestions on how to format code/ask questions on this site/how to approach problems like this. Thanks for your help!

```
int main () {
char mychar;
    int a;
    double op1;
    double op2;

    printf("Welcome to Andrew Hu's calculator program!\n"); //Greeting

    while(1)
    {    printf("Enter a mathematical operation to perform:\n");
        scanf("%c", &mychar);

    if(mychar == '+') //Valid Operators
        a = 1;
    else
        a = 0;


    if(a == 0) //Operator Checker, error if invalid
        printf("\nError, not a valid operator\n");
    else if(a == 1){
        printf("%c\n", mychar),
        printf("Enter OP1:\n"),
        scanf("%f", &op1),
        printf("%f\n", op1),
        printf("Enter OP2:\n"),
        scanf("%f\n", &op2),
        printf("%f\n", op2),
        printf("Result of %f %c %f = %f\n",
                op1, mychar, op2, (op1 + op2) );
    }
    }
```

Comment: For starters, its **`main()` {** , not `main {`. You could try posting code that *compiles*.

Comment: When you read `op2`, you have a newline in the format string; that's not correct.  Change that to read `scanf("%f", &op2);`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This actually solved all of my problems except the error message I get after a successful operation (see pic). Any additional insight? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical case where your teacher/tutor/book/online tutorial/whatever suggests that using `scanf()` is a good idea, whereas it really isn't. You should also not make any assumptions about line endings, and as a very last and marginal sidenote, you should structure your code better (formatting and consistency regarding curly braces included).

What I suggest you do is leave poor `scanf()` alone, it doesn't always do what you think it does, this is especially the case when there are single characters, strings and newline characters to read. Instead, you'd be better off reading a line and parsing and/or validating it. It will also be much simpler if you do it correctly.

> I also do not know how to tell my code that I am done inputting.

Well, you decide that. How about a `quit` operator? Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[0x100] = { 0 };

    while (1) {
        // If the user has entered "q", we enter the loop        
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        if (buf[0] == 'q') break;

        char *end;
        float op1 = strtof(buf, &end); // parse 1st operand

        while (isspace(*end)) {
            end++;
        }

        char op = *end++; // get operator

        float op2 = strtof(end, NULL); // parse 2nd operand
        float r;

        // do the calculation
        switch (op) {
        case '+':
            r = op1 + op2;
            break;
        case '-':
            r = op1 - op2;
            break;
        case '*':
            r = op1 * op2;
            break;
        case '/':
            r = op1 / op2;
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid operator '%c'\n", op);
            continue;
            break;
        }

        // print the result
        printf("%f %c %f = %f\n", op1, op, op2, r);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain to OP what was wrong with his code. Excellent answer though +1

Comment: @suspectus Thank you. Well, I've tried to do so... The main problem is that OP expected `scanf()` to do something it can't/doesn't do.

Comment: @AndrewHu To OP: 1. thanks for the accept, 2. you can of course use `double` and `strtod()` if you need better precision.

Comment: @H2CO3: Note that you can get the `%c` conversion specifier to ignore leading whitespace by putting a blank in front of it: `scanf(" %c", &mychar);`.

Comment: @JohnBode Yes, sure. A format string for this kind of input could be something like `%f[ ]%c[ ]%f[^\n]`, not sure if that's easier to read, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need %lf in scanf to read a double, otherwise you just read a float and store it in half the double...

```
  scanf("%lf", &op1),
```

This is not needed for printf because every float argument is first promoted to double...